# Dialogflow: manage several credentials for several agents

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow in python. I call the API V2 this way:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "project/xx-prototype-v2-xxxxx.json"
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
```

Now I need to access several agents with several .json credential files from the same python module.

Is there a smart way to setup this code for several dialogflow agents with each own credentials json-file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass authentication information when you instantiate `SessionClient` as seen in the sample code below:

```
const client = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
  credentials: {
    client_email: "svc-acc@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    private_key: "---BEGIN.....END-----"
  },
  projectId: "your-project-id"
})
```

For different agents/projects you can pass in different authentication information.  For example

```
const client1 = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
  credentials: {
    client_email: "service-account-email-1@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    private_key: "---BEGIN.....END-----" //service account private key 1
  },
  projectId: "your-project-id-1"
})
// use client1 and make any needed API calls to your first agent

const client2 = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
  credentials: {
    client_email: "service-account-email-2@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    private_key: "---BEGIN.....END-----" //service account private key 2
  },
  projectId: "your-project-id-2"
})
// use client2 and make any needed API calls to your second agent

// instantiate more clients as needed...
```

Comment: Thanks. Works fine. I also took from your solution that I need to construct the clientx only once at startup. That was not clear from the dialogflow python SDK.

Comment: Hmm: now I am having trouble with this solution. I get 430 IAM errors. Don't I need tokens somehow?